# How Python constructs path while calling files in different levels as they depend on other files and etc

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm strugling with understanding on how Python works within its project structure. I have created example of project structure and 3 files that communicate, 2 files are in 1st lvl project path and 1 file that calls those two is in the 2nd lvl of projects path.

## Example:

project_structure:

```
project_name/
    __init__.py
    package1/
        __init__.py
        file1.py
        file2.py
    config.json
    external.py
```

Now what is most interesting for is how Python uses paths...

### For example:

### project_name/config.json

```
{
    "data": "holds_data",
    "extra": {
        "some": 1,
        "is": "True"
    }
}
```

---

### project_name/external.py

```
def read_config():
    with open('config.json', 'r') as f:
        return = f.read()

config = read_config()

def do_some_job(data):
    action = config['data']
    if action == data:
        return 'Job is done!'
```

---

### project_name/package1/file1.py

```
from external import do_some_job

print(do_some_job('holds_data'))
```

---

What here happens, if I understand correctly:
When `project_name/package1/file1.py` calls `project_name/external.py` file it crashes as `FileNotFoundError` is given in `project_name/external.py` file while trying to find `project_name/package1/config.json` file.

Now do I understand it correctly:
When I call from `/package1/file1.py` the Python holds it's path as e.g. `C:/dev/project_name/package1`, and when it calls package in `C:/dev/project_name` file `/external.py` and in the line `with open('config.json', 'r') as f:` it gives the path `C:dev/project_name/package1/config.json`, but that file doesn't exists in there and it gives `FileNotFoundError`.

So my question is: what is the right way of working with paths and files within Python project structure?

## p.s.

I was looking for answer and I couldn't find the right one that explains how and why Python works as it is and how to manage it, I know that I might missed some documentation or somoe page that contains these details, so if it is, please don't be hard on me and give the link if you can, I would really apriciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, these are called *packages*. It can matter if you want to search about it in Python documentation, Google, or SO...

That been said, the package machinery works for importing modules (or importing identifiers from modules), but **not** for direct file access. Direct file access is still relative to the current working directory and can be different from the path of the current module.

If you use simple Python packages, meaning here a collection of files and folders and not an archive format like egg, things are simple. The `__file__` attribute of a module gives its full path. So your external.py file should be changed to:

```
import os.path

def read_config():
    # search config.json in module folder
    with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'config.json'), 'r') as f:
        return = f.read()

config = read_config()

def do_some_job(data):
    action = config['data']
    if action == data:
        return 'Job is done!'
```

If you need that to work in an egg, you should use the [`pkg_resources`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html) module from setuptools

Comment: Yes, that is what I needed, now I understand the way it works and how to work with it. Thank you very much @Serge Ballesta